# Parse server save data in series

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

So we have large data in `JSON` format.
We want to save it to a `class (table)` in our Parse app.
I wrote a JS script which can read the file and go through the `JSON` data.
But when is do the saving it all gets messed up. Its loops in the first one for ever. I understand that there is something called `promise` bt I don't understand how to use it? Can anyone help. My code is given below.

```
function processJson(result) {
object = JSON.parse(result);
verbose.textContent = "Read " + object.results.length + " objects";
var count = object.results.length;
var countAc = 0;
logger("To save: " + count);
i = 0;
while (i < count) {
    if (object.results[i].areaType == 'ac') {
        save(i).then(function (object) {
            i = i + 1;
            logger("Success: " + object.id);
        });
    } else {
        logger("ac not found");
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
}

function save(i) {
    logger("ac found");
    var constituency = new Constituency();
    constituency.set("points", object.results[i].points);
    constituency.set("areaType", object.results[i].areaType);
    constituency.set("name", object.results[i].name);
    constituency.set("state", object.results[i].state);
    constituency.set("index", object.results[i].index);
    constituency.set("pc", object.results[i].pc);
    constituency.set("center", object.results[i].center);
    constituency.set("oldObjectId", object.results[i].objectId);

return constituency.save();

/*constituency.save().then(function(obj) {
    // the object was saved successfully.
    i = i + 1;
    logger("Success: " + obj.id);
}, function(error) {
    // the save failed.
    logger(error.message);
    i = i + 1;
});*/
}
```

Comment: My guess is you do not want to `save(i)` you want to `save(object.results[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

```js
function processJson(result) {
  
  var object = JSON.parse(result);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < object.results.legnth; i++){
     var parseObject = createParseObjectFromJSONObject(object.results[i]);
     parseObject.save(null).then(function(object){
       console.log("object saved: " + object.id);
     },function(error){
        console.log("error: " + error);
     });
  }
  
}

function createParseObjectFromJSONObject(jsonObject){
   var constituency = new Constituency();
   constituency.set("points", jsonObject.points);
   constituency.set("areaType", jsonObject.areaType);
   constituency.set("name", jsonObject.name);
   constituency.set("state", jsonObject.state);
   constituency.set("index", jsonObject.index);
   constituency.set("pc", jsonObject.pc);
   constituency.set("center", jsonObject.center);
   constituency.set("oldObjectId", jsonObject.objectId); 
   return constituency;
}
```

**You can do it even better..**

You can first push all the parse objects into array and then call **saveAll** to save all the parse objects in one request. This solution is good for < 1000 records .. if you have more than 1000 then you can do paging (first 1000 and saveAll, other 1000 and saveAll ....)

In this version your code will look like this:

```js
    function processJson(result) {
      
      var object = JSON.parse(result);
      var allObjects = [];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < object.results.legnth; i++){
         var parseObject = createParseObjectFromJSONObject(object.results[i]);
         allObjects.push(parseObject);
      }
      
      // outside the loop we are ready to save all the objects in 
      // allObjects array in one service call!
      if (allObjects.length > 0){
        
          Parse.Object.saveAll(allObjects).then(function(){
            console.log("all objects were saved!");
            // all object ids are now available under the allObjects array..
          },function(error){
              console.log("error: " + error);
          });   
      }
  
    }

    function createParseObjectFromJSONObject(jsonObject){
       var constituency = new Constituency();
       constituency.set("points", jsonObject.points);
       constituency.set("areaType", jsonObject.areaType);
       constituency.set("name", jsonObject.name);
       constituency.set("state", jsonObject.state);
       constituency.set("index", jsonObject.index);
       constituency.set("pc", jsonObject.pc);
       constituency.set("center", jsonObject.center);
       constituency.set("oldObjectId", jsonObject.objectId); 
       return constituency;
    }
```

Good Luck :)